# Vanity url don't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, vanity-url

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [or]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://examplesite.com/vanity.php?un=$1 [NC]
```

php file

```
if(isset($_GET['un'])){

$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['un']);


$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='".$myusername."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1){echo 'hey' . $myusername;}
}
```

I enter the url http://examplesite.com/john and *I get http://examplesite/vanity.php?un=john with 'hey john' on page*, ***instead of url http://examplesite.com/john with 'hey john' on page**

This is the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZw4XJuRw3U), but I don't see where is the problem.

Comment: Please check if URL rewriting is enabled on your server

Comment: I have the hosting at godaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way I would do my rules. Try this way.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /vanity.php?un=$1 [NC,L]
```